# Problem with importing python classes from different folders

Tags: python, pycharm

This is how my project looks:

```
src/
     data_readers/ 
          - __init__.py
          - d2d_releases_reader.py
     main/
          d2d_interactions/
               - __init__.py
               - d2d_interactions_predictions.py
```

And from the `d2d_interactions_predictions.py` file I'm trying to import the class `d2d_releases_reader` inside the file `d2d_releases_reader.py` using the following:

```
from src.data_readers.d2d_releases_reader import d2d_releases_reader
```

It used to work but it just stopped randomly, I've no idea what happened and I'm trying to understand using other posts in Stack Overflow and I can't get it to work using any solution already proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to get it work playing around in PyCharm. I marked src directory as Sources Root, and then went to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and then did Invalidate caches and restart and this worked. To be honest I have no idea why was this needed as it worked before.